# how to spyOn or mock a function declaration/expression in testing?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to manipulate a function invoked in a module into giving true, however if the module doesn't encapsulate the functions onto an object, how can I mock the values of the function?

```js
  // app.js
  function start(foo) {
    if (isGood(foo)) initialize(foo)
  }
  function isGood = function(name) {
    return dosomething_really_complicated_here(name) // i dont care about this, and actuallyi want to mock its return value
  }

  function initialize(foo) {
    //... interesting stuff
  }

  // export {
  //  start as default,
  //  initialize
  // }


  // IN ANOTHER FILE
  // app.test.js
  // import app from './app'
  // const { start, initialize } = app

  describe('app', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      start('abc')
      // TODO: here I want to stub isGood to return true or false, note i could
      // TODO: i also want to spy on initialize
    })
    
    it('should call initialize', () => {
      expect(initializeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your own thoughts and preferences you can

1. Use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) or [babel-plugin-rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) to load tested module
   and replace deps with spies
2. Using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) and [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery) you can do *almost* the same
   like above.
3. You may expose private functionality in test environment and exclude
   it from production. See more in [this article](https://philipwalton.com/articles/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-javascript/)